# Vue.js: Get values of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have my own checkbox component (multi-checkbox-select from here: https://qvault.io/javascript/how-to-create-a-custom-checkbox-form-in-vue/). I would like to output the selected values of the checkboxes as text, but I get only the currently selected one.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<CustomCheckboxSelect
                v-model="optionsSelect"
                :options="options"
                checked="value"
                validation="required"
                input-has-errors-class="is-invalid"
                errors-class="invalid-feedback"
                error-behavior="submit"
                placeholder="Choose"
              />

<span class="test">{{ optionsSelect }}</span>
```

Comment: If CustomCheckboxSelect is your own component, perhaps it makes sense to add it to the question?

Comment: you're right. I just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your component is emitting an `input` so you need to read that in the parent

```
<CustomCheckboxSelect
                v-model="optionsSelect"
                :options="options"
                checked="value"
                validation="required"
                input-has-errors-class="is-invalid"
                errors-class="invalid-feedback"
                error-behavior="submit"
                placeholder="Choose"
                @input="checkboxValue"
              />
```

and in your `<script>` add a method that reads that

```
 methods: {
    checkboxValue: function (boxValue) {
        console.log(boxValue);
      }
    }
```